# steamworks C++ sdk. Detect client start already running game from single profile

Tags: c++, steam, steamworks-api

I have following sittuation.
Client_1 start game from Profile_1 in Computer_1, login in game, and play.
Client_2 start game from Profile_1 in Computer_2, login in game, and play.
For Client_1 steam show notification that another player connected, and terminate session. How Client_1 can handle in C++ code than another player start game from current profile? Is there any callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I resolve this issue. This is simplification of my implementation that allows to listen of particular events from steam.

```
class SteamCallbacksListener
{
private:
        STEAM_CALLBACK( SteamCallbacksListener, onSteamServersConnected, SteamServersConnected_t, mSteamConnectedListener );
        STEAM_CALLBACK( SteamCallbacksListener, onSteamServersDisconnected, SteamServersDisconnected_t, mSteamDisconnectedListener );
        STEAM_CALLBACK( SteamCallbacksListener, onSteamServerConnectFailure, SteamServerConnectFailure_t, mSteamConnectFilureListener );

         SteamCallbacksListener();
         SteamCallbacksListener( const SteamCallbacksListener& _copy );
        ~SteamCallbacksListener();

public:
        static SteamCallbacksListener* getInstance()
        {
            static SteamCallbacksListener instance;
            return &instance;
        }
};

SteamCallbacksListener::SteamCallbacksListener()
: mSteamConnectedListener( this, &SteamCallbacksListener::onSteamServersConnected )
, mSteamDisconnectedListener( this, &SteamCallbacksListener::onSteamServersDisconnected )
, mSteamConnectFilureListener( this, &SteamCallbacksListener::onSteamServerConnectFailure )
{
}

SteamCallbacksListener::~SteamCallbacksListener()
{
}

void SteamCallbacksListener::onSteamServersConnected( SteamServersConnected_t* _pParam )
{
}

void SteamCallbacksListener::onSteamServersDisconnected( SteamServersDisconnected_t* _pParam )
{
    if( _pParam )
    {
        switch( _pParam->m_eResult )
        {
            case k_EResultAlreadyLoggedInElsewhere:
            case k_EResultLoggedInElsewhere:
            case k_EResultPasswordRequiredToKickSession:
            {
                log( "This client already logged in. Error!" );
            }
            break;
        };
    }
}
```